# Windows 10 - running a puppeteer script opens a blank Chromium window

Tags: puppeteer

I am new to Puppeteer and am trying to run the example script. However, I get a blank chromium window (with no tab or URL bar).

```
Environment details:
    OS: Windows 10
    Node version: 8.4.0
    NPM version: 6.4.1
```

I installed puppeteer using NPM and version 1.0.0 got installed. I also installed version 1.9.0 directly from Puppeteer's github page. Both versions have a similar issue.

This is my script:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    try {
        console.log('starting');
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ 
            executablePath: 'D:/Code/Puppeteer/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/win64-594312/chrome-win/chrome.exe',
            headless: false 
        });
        console.log('one');
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        console.log('two');
        await page.goto('https://github.com');
        console.log('three');
        await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

        console.log("Page is up");
        await browser.close();
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log("Error: ", e);
    }
})();
```

In above script, I can see '**starting**' and then Chromium window opens with nothing on screen. When I press F12 to bring up the dev tool, I see '**one**' being printed on screen.

I have set environment variable '**path**' to use this:

`D:\Code\Puppeteer\node_modules\puppeteer\.local-chromium\win64-594312\chrome-win; C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application`

Comment: I've just run your script on my computer and everything works fine (Windows 10, Node 8.11.4, NPM 6.4.1, Puppeteer 1.9.0). I omitted the `executablePath` though, because it is not necessary. Is you're screenshot empty?

Comment: Yes @Bouke, the screen is empty.

Comment: How do I find out what version of puppeteer is being used in the script?

Comment: What happens if you try another url?

Comment: Display installed Puppeteer version on Windows: `npm list | findstr puppeteer`. On Linux: `npm list | grep puppeteer`. When looking for the global installed version, add the `--global` argument.

Comment: The puppeteer version is 1.9.0 and using a different URL makes no difference. In fact, the script stops at puppeteer.launch({})

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181481/discussion-between-sarvavyapi-and-bouke).

Comment: Ok, it is working now. I was running the node.js cmd window in admin mode and that did not work. Running in normal mode worked.

Answer (score 2):

The puppeteer script is working now. I started the node.js cmd window in admin mode to run the script which did not work. Running in normal mode worked.

Comment: I had the same issue on `Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Datacenter`. I was running the scripts in Administrator mode. As soon as I switched to non-admin powershell window, it worked!